# jQuery Data Table Not Working In Liferay 7.x

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, datatables, liferay

I am new to liferay and liferay 7.x development. I am following this [blog](https://web.liferay.com/web/meera.success/blog/-/blogs/liferay-jquery-data-table). I tried first two examples on liferay 6.2 and examples are working perfectly. But when i tried these example on liferay 7.x. I am getting  this error.

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).DataTable is not a function
>
> ```
> at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (<anonymous>:1:46)
> at j (jquery-1.11.1.min.js:2)
> at Object.add [as done] (jquery-1.11.1.min.js:2)
> at m.fn.init.m.fn.ready (jquery-1.11.1.min.js:2)
> at <anonymous>:1:13
> ```

**This is my view.jsp:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/css/jquery.dataTables.css">

 <script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#userTable').DataTable();
            } );
 </script>
</head>
<body>
<table id="userTable" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
       <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>63</td>
                <td>2011/07/25</td>
                <td>$170,750</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>66</td>
                <td>2009/01/12</td>
                <td>$86,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
                <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>2012/03/29</td>
                <td>$433,060</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Airi Satou</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>33</td>
                <td>2008/11/28</td>
                <td>$162,700</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2012/12/02</td>
                <td>$372,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
                <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>59</td>
                <td>2012/08/06</td>
                <td>$137,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>55</td>
                <td>2010/10/14</td>
                <td>$327,900</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Colleen Hurst</td>
                <td>Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>39</td>
                <td>2009/09/15</td>
                <td>$205,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Sonya Frost</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>23</td>
                <td>2008/12/13</td>
                <td>$103,600</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: use $("#id").dataTable check the case in here, some bugs are logged in git-hub for the initialization with case, Check this fiddle although its working with both. https://jsfiddle.net/gemmcs1u/
Also check this page https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/35258/uncaught-type-error-datatable-is-not-a-function

Comment: @VinaySingh i tried your solution but it is not working on Liferay 7.

Comment: Note that a portlet's view.jsp must not continue `<html>`, `<head>` or `<body>` tags. This might lead to unexpected behavior. Plus, working with `id`s in a portlet might result in duplicated ids on the page if somebody else (or your portlet in a second instance on the same page) chooses the same name for the attribute. You should make it unique by adding `<portlet:namespace/>` to it.

Comment: @OlafKock. Thank you for you useful suggestions. I removed <html>, <head> and <body> tags from my view.jsp and i added <portlet:namespace/> before id. But still it is not working. The same code is working perfectly on liferay 6.2..